# How to replace an extras value?

Tags: android, extras

I am a beginner in android programming and I couldn't find a way to replace an extra value

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    list_1= new Intent(this,Ekran1.class);
    list_2= new Intent(this,Ekran2.class);
    list_2.putExtra("iname", "2");
    if(position==0)
    {
        startActivity(list_1);
        if(list_2.getExtras().getString("iname")=="2")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iname=2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopService(list_2);
        }
        else if(list_2.getExtras().getString("iname") =="3")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "iname=3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stopService(list_2);
        }
    }
    else if(position==1)
    {
        list_2.putExtra("iname", "1");
        startActivity(list_2);
        stopService(list_1);
    }
```

I want to change iname value to 1 but it has always value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, compare Strings with equals()

```
if (list_2.getExtras().getString("iname").equals("2"))
```

The values in extras are not intended to be replaced.
You put extras to pass the data when Activity is started.

It's hard to understand your intentions, but if the *iname* must be changed in *Ekran*, you should rather call

```
startActivityForResult(ekranIntent, requestCode)
```

and analyze the data returned in

```
onActivityResult()
```

Overridden in your current Activity.